# How to exchange QGIS legend symbology into ESRI ArcGIS?

Tags: symbology, legend, import, layer-file, qml

Is there a possibility to import the legend symbology, which has been created in QGIS, to Esri ArcGIS?

Or a possibility, to create a .lyr file from QGIS?

Comment: You might have more luck with an international standard (SLD) which I'm sure ESRI will support.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question for GIS SE.